# Magic Trackpad 2 with Fedora 25

Tags: linux, magic-trackpad

I'm trying to make my Magic Trackpad 2 work on Fedora with all it's features (or at least some basics). The current (default) state is moving the mouse and left-clicking works out of the box, but right click (double fingers click) or scroll doesn't work, which is a huge issue.

I've been Googling to find the solution and everything I've found is dating back from January 2016, so at least a year old.

I believe that there has been some major improvements since then. I read that Ubuntu started handling multi-touch support in 10.10 so I believe it should be widely working as of today.

I've saw that some people recommend [mtrack](https://github.com/BlueDragonX/xf86-input-mtrack/issues/105), others [Ginn](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/AppleMagicTrackpad#Using_Ginn_for_multi-touch_gesture_inputs).

Ideally, it would be awesome to have here a place that explains in great length how to configure a Linux system to support the Magic Trackpad 2 in the best way possible (up to the latest possibilities, like three-finger tracking, etc), using either Synaptics, libinput, mtrack or ginn. Whatever works best.

If someone already has a Magic Trackpad 2 working well under Linux, it would be great to get some help.

Thanks :)